# symfony web-service with username and password

Tags: symfony, web-services, passwords

I will not post any of my code, because this is more just a question to know if it's possible.
I've been googling a lot, but didn't find any concrete solutions. I hope someone can help me here.

**The facts:**

- I have a login form
- I need to authenticate the credentials over a web-service
- I need to send both username and password, to get back a token if logged in successfully.

**The problems:**

- With a custom provider I'm always stuck with the fact that they only have direct access to the userename, like: loadUserByUsername. I need to access the password there as well, to be able to send this to my web-service.
- I have only 1 web-service which sends only back a token if provided username and password are correct.

**Question:**

How can I access and send both username and password to my web-service?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking one would authenticate using an [API token](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/api_key_authentication.html) to a web service.

That API token is usually issued via an auto-generation script when the user account is created (either by an admin or by a registration form).  This token is then passed by the API call to the web-service in a header which then uses it to authenticate the user.

As far as Symfony goes, by far the easiest way of doing this is with Guard.  A new component built by Ryan Weaver from KNP.

KNPUniversity has a [great tutorial](https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/guard) on it (for free).

Note that this is only one option of many, and the 'best' way is probably mainly opinion based and directly related to the use case in question.  But it might help you get on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

If the token you want to create should be a JSON Web Token (JWT), a very conventient bundle is [LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle](https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle), which does almost all of the work automatically. If you just follow the documentation, you will have it quickly up and running. You can combine it with FOSUserBundle, with a custom User entity or whatever.